# Discord.py | Toggle commands locally

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm currently trying to make a command that can toggle commands. It works, however I want it to disable the given command(s) *only for that server, and then store this data somewhere* - currently, toggling a command will enable / disable it in EVERY server.

This is my code so far:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def toggleCommand(ctx, *, command):
        command = client.get_command(command)

        if command is None:
            await ctx.send("I can't find a command with that name!")

        elif ctx.command == command:
            await ctx.send("You cannot disable this command.")

        else:
            command.enabled = not command.enabled
            ternary = "enabled" if command.enabled else "disabled"
            await ctx.send(f"I have {ternary} {command.qualified_name} for you!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have a database with a structure of `guild_id | commands_disabled`. The `commands_disabled` would most likely have to be a list of the command names. You could then retrieve the disabled commands from the database by `SELECT * FROM db_table WHERE guild_id = {guild.id}`

The context passed contains a guild object.